Can I use TypeScript 5.0 decorators with React?
When I apply decorators to my class they are always called with the arguments for legacy decorators: a target, property key, and property descriptor.
I would like to use TypeScript 5.0 decorators. Is this possible, and if so, how can I enable it? Thank you.

post your tsconfig.json please.

Can [edit] your question to incllude the code you are using and any error messages you are getting? Can you replicate the issue in the Typescript playground?

To get the legacy decorator behavior, you have to opt in with the experimentalDecorators config option.
See: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#experimentalDecorators
You must have that set in your tsconfig.json. Remove that option from your config, and Typescript just be setup to use the new decorators instead.

Removing this flag or setting it to false does not work.
